# Script that open telnet connection and send message via socket to a server

Tags: bash, sockets, telnet

I must do a script that run a connection telnet and send to a server two numbers. I am sure that server work because if I send values directly from telnet everything works correctly. If I run the script that do exactly what I do something does not work. I can see client has been connected, but I don't see on screen the numbers that should be had sent via telnet.

Here the script (really simple):

```
{ echo "3"; echo "6"; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 8887
```

and part of the server :

```
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
server.sin_port = htons(8887);

...
//bind and listen
...

printf("connesso\n");

//Riceve un emssaggio dal client
for(i=0; i<2;) {

    bzero(client_message,2000);

    if((read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0)
    {
        //Rimanda indietro il messaggio al client
        write(client_sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));

        numeri[i]=atoi(client_message);
        i++;            
    }
}

...
// some check
...

if(numeri[1] % numeri[0] == 0) {
    printf("multiplo\n");
}
else {
    printf("negativo\n");
}
```

So, I should see on server some messages:

1. "Connesso"
2. "multiplo" or "negativo"

But i see just "Connesso"... It's like i do not receive nothing.. Obviously i see "connesso" after I run my script.

Any idea?

Thanx

Comment: Maybe Nagle's algorithm gets in the way? (IIRC telnet behaves differently depending on portno and whether stdin is a tty)

Comment: Mm i dunno.. I need something really easy... I mean that i could not have control on server side.. But just on the script

Comment: Try putting some printf()s inside the loop. And check the returnvalue (read_size) you get from recv() in or after the loop.

Comment: Try listening on INADDR_ANY maybe? Try showing your `bind()` and `listen()` code too.

Answer (score 2):

This code will work

```
{ echo "3"; echo "6"; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 8887
```

How I tested it? Install netcat. Then from one terminal

```
nc -l 8887
```

And from another terminal type

```
{ echo "3"; echo "6"; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 8887
```

You will see the number 3 and 6 in the first terminal running nc

Comment: My purpose is not to use nc with telnet... i'm sorry

Comment: I showed you nc example to show the bash syntax is fine, nc was used for troubleshooting purpose only.